# Getting "TypeError: Object of type IFDRational is not JSON serializable" while trying to json.dumps EXIF info

Tags: django

I'm trying to extract EXIF information from an image and store it as a `JSONField`.
It works well for some image types but not for others.

Below my code:

```
image_open = Image.open(self.image)
image_open.verify()
image_getexif = image_open.getexif()
if image_getexif:
    exif = {
        ExifTags.TAGS[k]: v for k, v in image_getexif.items() if k in ExifTags.TAGS and type(v) is not bytes]
    }
    print(json.dumps(exif, indent=4))
```

I'm getting `TypeError: Object of type IFDRational is not JSON serializable` when trying to `json.dumps()`.

When dumping the exif dict I notice it is pretty standard so not sure what this is about.

```
{'ResolutionUnit': 2, 'ExifOffset': 204, 'Make': 'Apple', 'Model': 'iPhone 13', 'Software': '15.3.1', 'Orientation': 1, 'DateTime': '2022:03:04 17:35:15', 'XResolution': 72.0, 'YResolution': 72.0, 'HostComputer': 'iPhone 13'}
```

Answer (score 1):

When checking for `type` on each of the items you can see that some items in the dict are actually of type `PIL.TiffImagePlugin.IFDRational`.

```
for (k, v) in image_getexif.items():
    print(k, type(k))
    print(v, type(v))
```

This outputs:

```
296 <class 'int'>
2 <class 'int'>
34665 <class 'int'>
204 <class 'int'>
271 <class 'int'>
Apple <class 'str'>
272 <class 'int'>
iPhone 13 <class 'str'>
305 <class 'int'>
15.3.1 <class 'str'>
274 <class 'int'>
1 <class 'int'>
306 <class 'int'>
2022:03:04 17:35:15 <class 'str'>
282 <class 'int'>
72.0 <class 'PIL.TiffImagePlugin.IFDRational'>
283 <class 'int'>
72.0 <class 'PIL.TiffImagePlugin.IFDRational'>
316 <class 'int'>
iPhone 13 <class 'str'>
{}
<class 'dict'>
{}
```

Add these to the exclusions (or cast them to `int` if required) and you're good to go.

```
if k in ExifTags.TAGS and type(v) not in [bytes, TiffImagePlugin.IFDRational]
```

Import the TiffImagePlugin from PIL:

```
from PIL import Image, ExifTags, TiffImagePlugin
```